# Native Google Drive MIME types failing to save in Drive UI integration

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm working on a Google Drive UI "Open with" integration.

I'm trying to populate the "Secondary MIME Types" with Google Doc & Google Spreadsheet mime types (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types) in Google Cloud Console under Google Drive API config.

They are as follows:

> application/vnd.google-apps.document
> application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet

However, the form throws a bad request every time I add either of those mime types.

The following does WORK:
[image]

The following does NOT WORK:
[image]

Anyone else run into this issue, and how have they solved it? According to Google's own docs (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/enable-sdk) it should be allowed.

Comment: Could you please provide exactly what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you do not need to include the google specific mime types in order for your app to show up under "Open with" for docs, slides & spreadsheets.

Adding the `application/pdf` mime type should suffice, then google drive passes the `exportIds` as a query parameter to your open URL. You can then use that id in conjunction with the google drive API export file method (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) to export the document as a PDF.